# How to get values in data-parameter of jQuery.get(......)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

I have tried the following `jQuery` code to navigate `result1.html` using `$.get`:

```
var proc = function (resp) {
    alert('finished');
};

$.get('result1.html',     // url
    'read me if you can', // data
    proc,                 // success
    'html');              // datatype
```

The second parameter (data) is filled with the string "*read me if you can*". Is there a way to get the value of data "*read me if you can*" in result1.html with `jquery` or `javascript`?

Contributions and solutions are thankfully welcome!

Comment: Of course there is, that's the whole point, using a serverside language. Which one are you using, in PHP it would be `$_GET['key']` etc.

Comment: He asked for reading it with jquery or javascript. I think you misunderstood `$.get`. This function does not navigate or something. It just get's an file or page. So no, you can't do this with any js on the page you get.

Comment: You can't get the data with JavaScript on the same page. You are supposed to send that to the server, process it and then the server  will send a response back.

Comment: Oh, not sure why you would use javascript and not the serverside to get the querystring, but Barmar is right, you can access that with `location.search` in `result1.html`, but noone does that, learn a serverside language instead.

Comment: Technically, the data is already on the page. All you have to do is make a variable with it before sending it. I don't see the point of this or you want to do something else.

Comment: I was wrong, and I've deleted my answer. Javascript is only interpreted when you load a page into the browser. Accessing an HTML page with AJAX doesn't load it, so the Javascript is never executed. And even if you use `$.load()`, which does execute scripts in the loaded page, `location.search` would be the parameters of the calling page, not the target page.